# How to make the event highlight only a certain part of the row in the day cell and not the complete row in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have implemented my calendar in `defaultView: month` where the events, if occurring on a day are being shown the whole day even if they are occurring during a part of the day. I want them to be displayed only in a part of the day, not in the whole day cell.

I don't want to show the times. My day is comprising of 8 hours: 8AM to 6PM. If an event is happening between 8AM and 9AM, then only the first 1/8th of the day cell is selected/highlighted in the cell, and not the whole cell. In other words, I want to reduce the size of the event depending on how long the event is in the day.

Another example, if the event is covering the first 4 hours of the day, then the event should be shown only in the first half of the cell and not the complete cell.

How can I do that?

**Code Snippet:**

```
$('#div_calendar').fullCalendar({
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    theme: true,

    header: {
        right: 'next',
        center: 'title, ',
        left: 'prev'
    },

    eventSources: [
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/GetHolidays',
            dataType: 'json',
            className: 'bgm-green',
            textColor: 'white'
        },
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/GetLeaves',
            dataType: 'json',
            className: 'bgm-amber',
            textColor: 'white'
        }
    ]
});
```

**Kindly read the comments for more information**

Comment: this is exactly what the "agenda" style views are for. Why don't you want to use that, and make your life a lot easier?  Also you don't appear to have made any attempt to solve this yourself, and it could be potentially complex. SO isn't a hire-a-free-programmer service - we'll help you fix your code, if you've got any, but we won't just come up with a whole solution to a large-ish problem like this, for free.

Comment: Also, events in month view don't take up the "whole" cell, they only take up one row of it. If you add 2 or 3 events on one day you can see they are placed in separate rows.

Comment: Yeah. What I meant by the whole cell was that the event takes up one whole row. I want to cover only a part of the row and not the full row for an event that is there only for a part of the day. Example, if an event is for the last 4 hours of a 8 hour day, then the event should be seen covering the second half of the row and not the whole row. Can I do that?

Comment: you can do anything, in theory. Have a look at the HTML and see how you might amend it or the CSS to achieve that. Have a look at the fullCalendar docs and see if any of the options or callbacks might provide you with an environment where you could do it on the fly with each event (based on its data), or whether you need to change the source code. Like I said before, you don't seem to have done at all anything about this yet, it's too early to ask a question. Questions on SO are for when you have a more specific, detailed problem, rather than a larger aspiration or requirement like this.

Comment: I understand. I am already getting events in my calendar. I have gone through the fullCalendar docs and I couldn't find anything that is in the lines of what I want to do. I am getting events to cover full row even of it is for just 2 hours in the day. My requirement is to reduce the size proportional to the number of hours the event is for.

Comment: Ok, but none of that changes what I wrote above regarding your question. Fundamentally though, the "month" view is not designed to display time-related information, only date-related. Which is why I think you should just use the "agenda" type views, they're designed for displaying time very clearly to the user. You can make them display more days at once, if that helps. But if you want to pursue this, you'll have to do some more research for yourself, I suspect it will not be easy to make it cover all circumstances accurately. You may even need to create an entirely custom view.

Comment: Yes. From what I have understood till now is that, with the help of the `CSS` code, we can manage the background color, the font, and the font color. I could not find a way to manage the length of the event being displayed in the date cell. This is because, the length of the event in the date cell is managed by the start date and time and end date and time of the event. 

@ADyson I want to understand whether this understanding of mine is correct or not?

Comment: "This is because, the length of the event in the date cell is managed by the start date and time and end date and time". Not in month view - the time is not taken into consideration, except in terms of deciding what order the events appear in. The exact time does not play a part - the first event of the day will be in the same place, whether it starts at 9am or 1pm or 5pm etc. That's as much as I know - it's obvious enough from watching how the calendar behaves. If you want to understand it in further detail, you can read the source code.

Comment: @ADyson I think I have a solution. Say I have an event that runs for 5 days. I have saved the event in the database like that only and I am retrieving the data in JSON format. Can I break the big event into 5 smaller events? if yes, then I think I can manage the length of the event on the starting day and ending day depending on what time they are ending. What do you think about this? Is there way to perform this?

Comment: I mean, say we have an event for 5 days. Can we break it into 5 small events and put one event in one day. The event data will remain the same in the database where it will still show 5 days as the duration.

Comment: This has to be done dynamically though!

Comment: "Can I break the big event into 5 smaller events?" Of course it's possible, you have complete control over what data you give to the calendar. You can either do that on the server before you return the JSON, or you can do it in Javascript if you have a custom event feed (i.e. implementing using this pattern: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . I don't really see how it's relevant to the original question though - if you have a way to manage the length of the event in the display, you can do that with any timed event, no matter whether it was multi-day or not